# I can't get the value of position

Tags: flutter, dart

I don' know why i didn't get currentPosition. Please help me.

Here my code

```
 FutureProvider(
          create: (context) async => await locatorService.getLocation(),
          initialData: null,
        ),

final currentPosition = Provider.of<Position?>(context);
```

[Here my main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHNzh.png)

[Here where i want to get currentPosition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRnrB.png)

Comment: did you add the permission for location in manifest or info.plist file 
also you have to check first you app have the permission to get the location data

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)